# Spring 3 - Context Initialization Error BeanCurrentlyInCreationException

Tags: spring, dependencies, applicationcontext

We are currently using Spring 3.2.8-RELEASE, heavily relying on @Autowired annotations in our code. Whilst starting the application we are getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'XXXXX': Bean with name 'XXXXX' has been injected into other beans [XXXXX,XXXXX] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually 
been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. 
This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
```

1) We do not have any circular reference in bean dependencies.
2) The system works on all development machines (mix of Windows and Linux machines), the testing server and one of our production servers. The error is only occurring on one of our servers. The only difference between this server is the OS used. On this server, we are using The following are the details of this server.

```
LSB Version: :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description: CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Release: 6.5
Codename: Final
```

Comment: Is the JDK version the same on these machines?

Comment: Yes, we have the same JDK versions

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue, i am using Ubuntu 14.10 in my laptops. when deploying my war file on my first machine I encountered the 'BeanCurrentlyInCreationException' but in my sencond machine, deployment is okay. By the way I am using IntelliJ as my IDE.

Comment: In reality we did not solve this problem. My impression was that this was the result of bad design in the first place. For this reason we refactored our services.